# Rails Using Devise to show Online users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I would like to show my online users in a Who's online module.

I'm using Devise to manage my users.

I searched everywhere, but I don't have any idea to manage it.

Do you have a clue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am wondering the same thing. I consider adding an "isOnline" variable to the user-class, but I don't know if this is best-practice or even safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when someone has logged in, you can push him into an array, if someone has logged out, just remove him from the array. So you can loop the array items to show the online users.
Hope it is useful to you.
Sorry for my poor english.