# How can I tell whether a given Devise user is signed in right now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

In a Rails app that uses Devise, is there a way to tell if a **specific** user is signed in **right now**?

I know about the view helper, `user_signed_in?`. What I'm looking for is more like:

```
User.all.each do |user|
  puts user.signed_in?
end
```

I see that Devise has added a `current_sign_in_at` column to `users`. But that doesn't get set to `NULL` when the user signs out, so I can't test with that.

How can I check whether a user is currently signed in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504130/whos-online-using-devise-in-rails, but the answers to both questions have good points.

Comment: Not sure what I was originally thinking. HTTP is stateless. Whether someone is signed in "now" is a meaningless question unless they're currently making a request. The closest we could get is "for what users do we have sessions in the db that are not older than X, such that if they made a request right now with the corresponding cookie, we would consider it valid?"

Comment: Right. Most of the answers have to do with whether a user has made a request in the last x minutes. I didn't know how to peek into sessions (which I store in cookies), so I went with a modified version of [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!starred/plataformatec-devise/R2dou7yp27s), basically updating a User.last_request_at field on each request (except I throttle updates to once per minute).

Answer (score 6):

You can add a **before_filter** to your ApplicationController to set the current date/time in the **last_request_at** field in your users table, which you'd have to add first via a migration. In the method called from the before_filter, you wanna make sure that the user is authenticated first, of course. And you may want to except the filter for actions not requiring authentication.

Then, assuming you've included the **Timeoutable** module in your User model, you can see if the user's session is current or not by making a call like this:

```
user.timedout?(user.last_request_at)
```

The **timedout?(last_access)** method, defined in the Timeoutable module, will compare the Devise session timeout with the last request time/date.

As a side note, you might want to only update last_request_at if the last last_request_at value is greater than a minute ago (or any time interval you choose). Otherwise, if your page makes lots of controller calls, like mine does via AJAX, there are a lot of unnecessary db updates in one request.

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to track if the user is signed in and has a session active, or if the user is on the site right now?

For tracking if the user is signed in, you would need to add a callback to Warden and update a timestamp every time a page loads and then if they haven't done anything for longer than X time period you assume they are logged out. You can do this with:

```
Warden::Manager.after_authentication do |user, auth, opts|
    if user.last_action <= 5.minutes.ago.utc
        user.last_action = Time.now
        user.save
    end
end
```

If you want to see if the have an active season and haven't explicitly logged out, it would be something such as:

```
Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user, auth, opts|
    user.current_sign_in_at = nil
    user.save
end
```

Comment: Do you know whether the `before_logout` block will run if the user is automatically logged out, like with Devise's `timeoutable`?

Comment: It's run whenever the Warden `logout` method is used which handles cleaning up the session. Specifically for `timedoutable` it'll run for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Add an active flag to your user (devise) model.  In the application controller under the `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` hook set the active flag to true(happens when the user successfully creates a new session).

for loged out user, override the destroy method in the devise session_controller and set the active flag to false, then call super.

Now you can call user.active? on any user.

Answer (score 0):

Devise comes with a method `current_user` that will return the current user in controllers, models, and views.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. `current_user` is scoped to a session, so to speak; if 5 people are logged into my site right now, all looking at the same page which displays the value of `current_user`, they will each see themselves. What I want is a way, as a site admin, to list all 5 of those logged-in users, or to ask "is someuser@example.com signed in right now or not?"