# Rails - How to check for online users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the best way checking how many users that are current online on a page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to add a last_online timestamp to your User model, then define a scope for user called online_now

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.online_now
    where("last_online > ?", 15.minutes.ago)
  end
end
```

Comment: And how do you fill "last_online" field?

Answer (score 15):

### Keep in Redis

Like *Yuri Barbashow's* [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8518787/1816872) but using **Redis** ([nice introdution for Rails](http://jimneath.org/2011/03/24/using-redis-with-ruby-on-rails.html#redis_and_rails)):

```rb
# config/initializers/redis.rb

$redis_onlines = Redis.new
# it's the simplest way, but i'd recommend:
# $redis_onlines = Redis.new path: "/tmp/redis.sock", db: 15, driver: :hiredis
# => hiredis driver more fast
# => use unix domain socket if it's possible
# => default db is No.0, but it is better to use a specific database
#    and No.0 leave for testing-development-and-more-and-more
```

Gemfile

```rb
# Gemfile

gem 'redis'
gem 'hiredis' # optional
# don't forget to run `bundle`
```

Set to `online`

```rb
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
after_filter :set_online
# the Rails 4 way is:
# after_action :set_online

private

  # set to online
  def set_online
    if !!current_user
      # using separate Redis database
      # such as $redis_onlines = Redis.new db: 15
      # value not need, only key
      $redis_onlines.set( current_user.id, nil, ex: 10*60 )
      # 'ex: 10*60' - set time to live - 10 minutes
    end
  end
```

Is online?

```rb
# app/models/user.rb

def online?
  $redis_onlines.exists( self.id )
end
```

And small bonus (if you are using separate redis database)

```rb
# app/cpntrollers/application_controller.rb

def all_who_are_in_touch
  $redis_onlines.keys
  # => [ "123", "234", "1", "23" ]
  # array of ids
end
```

---

#### #UDP1 rework for anonymous

Set to `online`

```rb
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb

  def set_online
    if !!current_user
      $redis_onlines.set( "user:#{current_user.id}", nil, ex: 10*60 )
    else
      $redis_onlines.set( "ip:#{request.remote_ip}", nil, ex: 10*60 )
    end
  end
```

Is online?

```rb
# app/models/user.rb

def online?
  $redis_onlines.exists( "user:#{self.id}" )
end
```

All who are in touch:

```rb
# app/cpntrollers/application_controller.rb

def all_signed_in_in_touch
  ids = []
  $redis_onlines.scan_each( match: 'user*' ){|u| ids << u.gsub("user:", "") }
  ids
end

def all_anonymous_in_touch
  $redis_onlines.scan_each( match: 'ip*' ).to_a.size
end

def all_who_are_in_touch
  $redis_onlines.dbsize
end
```

---

#### #UDP2 Recommendations

1. Use a `before_filter` instead of a `after_filter`

```rb
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  before_filter :set_online # before_action for Rails 4
```

2. If you watch the anonymous (for example `session[:user_id]` is id of current user)

```rb
# app/controllers/session_controller.rb
  before_filter :clear_from_signed_in_touch, only: :destroy
  before_filter :clear_from_anonymous_in_touch, only: :create

  private

    def clear_from_anonymous_in_touch
      $redis_onlines.del( "ip:#{request.remote_ip}" )
    end

    def clear_from_signed_in_touch
      $redis_onlines.del( "user:#{session[:user_id]}" )
    end
```

Postscript: [Redis](http://redis.io/) | [set](http://redis.io/commands/set) | [exists](http://redis.io/commands/exists) | [expire](http://redis.io/commands/expire) | [scan](http://redis.io/commands/scan) | [scan_each](http://rdoc.info/github/redis/redis-rb/Redis#scan_each-instance_method) | [redis-rb](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb) | [hiredis](https://github.com/redis/hiredis-rb) | [nice introduction for beginners](http://jimneath.org/2011/03/24/using-redis-with-ruby-on-rails.html)