# Listing users online

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36397416/cant-manage-out-how-to-show-users-online) question I asked how to list out users currently online in the chat. While discussing I was given an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805479/rails-how-to-check-for-online-users), and I tried to implement it, but I didn't succeed. So, I made a migration `add_last_online_to_users last_online:datetime` and made a tweak in `User` model:

**`user.rb`**:

```
def self.online_now
  where ("last_online > ?", 15.minutes.ago)
end
```

And then added to my `Message` controller, so that each time an user sends a message, his `last_online` updates to `Time.now`. Finally, I added to my `application_controller` the following code:

```
def show_online
  @users = User.online_now
end
```

and called that method in my view:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <%= user.show_online %>
<% end %>
```

that returned me a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But it returned me an error that `online_now` column doesn't exist in
>   database

You cannot query with a ***method***, so `@users = User.where(online_now: true)` won't work. Instead you have to do like below

```
def show_online
  @users = User.online_now
end
```

Comment: I tried your answer and in returns me `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`. I've updated my question with a piece of code that makes the issue

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 That means there are no records matching that condition.

Comment: because there's no users?

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 Yes there are no records matching that condition.

Comment: so if I want the chat to work even if there's no users online, should I put that in something like `if @users.any?`

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 Put that in `if !@users.blank?`

Comment: so that helped but there's another problem that I checked via console - although I added to my sessions and messages controller that when user sends message his `last_online` updates to `Time.now`, my column `last_online` of the user remains `nil`

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 Please ask another question explaining your problem detail. As of now accept my answer as it solved your current problem :)

Answer (score 0):

No problem with your codes.
I think your view and your controller/action are different. It mean you try show @users to another view not "**show_online.html.erb**"

You just have a syntax error in your model

```
where ("last_online > ?", 15.minutes.ago)
```

should be

```
where("last_online > ?", 15.minutes.ago)
```