# Find online users using devise and rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using devise as a good way of authentication in my rails 3.2 application and I tried several ways to fetch online users ,I need to know if I can fetch all online users using sessions on my application

Comment: You mean currently logged in users? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I mean all online users on the site now ...

Comment: Forget about sessions. The best soluton is http://stackoverflow.com/a/21396780/5048945
Redis doesn't use your database. it fast and works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google and stackoverflow are your friends:

There appears to be a gem for this and has been asked a lot.

["Who's Online" using Devise in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504130/whos-online-using-devise-in-rails)

Comment: these solution and other answers provided me to check if the user is online and was online since 1 min ago or more ,,but if the user close the browser or the session destroy the user is still online with all of these approaches

Comment: Your question is not clear. Perhaps consider being more descriptive to get better answers. That's probably why you got marked down. Moreover, I don't think finding your immediately connected users has anything to do with devise. Your app would need to poll them instead.

Comment: I think you are right ,,thanks for answering me ..I will find another solution ...

Comment: and you are right my question wasn't clear ,,I think it was better to ask ,,how can I implement online/offline feature like facebook ...and thanks again for your answers

Comment: In html5, btw, I think you can do something like if (navigator.onLine) {// Do something}. Although if you look through Google you'll find something better. S

Comment: @AndrewIce what a silly thing to say - if you feel an answer made over a year ago is out of date, don't mark it down, correct it or leave a constructive comment at least.

Comment: @simonmorley pretty sure I never marked it down.  I simply commented on it. That would be rude to do. I also left constructive criticism, in my comment.  Although apparently 'someone' deleted it. Since I remember specifically that I was mentioning about who the gem above was years out of date.

Yeah, looking at my activity. I never earned a -1 for this post.