# Rails: how to show user's "last seen at" time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using devise which stores `current_sign_in_at` and `last_sign_in_at` datetimes.

**But lets say a user logged in a month ago but last viewed a page 5 minutes ago?**

Is there a way I can display that (**"User last seen 5 minutes ago"**).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

How about this:

1. Create a migration to add a new field to users to store the date and time the user was last seen:

   ```
   rails g migration add_last_seen_at_to_users last_seen_at:datetime
   ```
2. Add a before action callback to your application controller:

   ```
   before_action :set_last_seen_at, if: proc { user_signed_in? }

   private
   def set_last_seen_at
     current_user.update_attribute(:last_seen_at, Time.current)
   end
   ```

This way, on every request (i.e. activity) that the current user performs, his/her last seen at attribute is updated to the current time.

Please note, however, that this may take up some of your app's resources if you have many users who are logged in, because this will execute before every controller action requested by someone who is logged in.

If performance is a concern, consider adding the following throttle mechanism to step 2 (in this example, throttling at 15 minutes):

```
before_action :set_last_seen_at, if: proc { user_signed_in? && (session[:last_seen_at] == nil || session[:last_seen_at] < 15.minutes.ago) }

private
def set_last_seen_at
  current_user.update_attribute(:last_seen_at, Time.current)
  session[:last_seen_at] = Time.current
end
```

Comment: Thanks Charles. That's my concern -- is there a way to accomplish this with the lowest resource use possible? An update to the db with each page view will be too much :)

Comment: @Hopstream See edit. I added a throttled example to only execute this method after x minutes, thereby considerably saving resources.

Comment: There's no point in using a session variable for the throttling here. Just use the `current_user.last_seen_at` value directly.

Comment: @RyanMcGeary wouldn't that create an extra db call to get that value vs using the session variable?

Comment: @Lorenz No. The  `current_user` was already fetched from the database and with it, the `last_seen_at` value at the same time.

Comment: Should that say session[:last_seen_at] < 15.minutes.ago or session[:last_seen_at] > 15.minutes.ago?  Shouldn't it be _more_ than 15 minutes ago, not _less_?

Comment: @Lorenz Your thinking is correct; however, these are two timestamps that we're comparing. `x < 15.minutes.ago?` reads like English so it's confusing, but what it really means is "Is this timestamp x less than the timestamp from 15 minutes ago". Which is the same as asking "Was this more than 15 minutes ago", because a timestamp that's further in the past will be smaller. Hope this clears things up :)

Comment: it's better to use `update_column` instead of `update_attribute` - otherwise you're updating `updated_at` also as well as triggering all callbacks defined on User model, which most likely is not the desired behavior

Answer (score 9):

To improve performance of the previous answer:

- don't use session, as user already loaded with warden and all the attributes are accessible
- `update_attribute` runs callbacks and updates `updated_at` attribute, and `update_column` not
- to improve performance, better to use background workers, like ActiveJob/Resque/Sidekiq
- to prevent from the high DB locking, better to create a seperate table, associated with users table, and write accesses there

Updated code:

```
before_action :set_last_seen_at, if: proc { user_signed_in? && (user.last_seen_at.nil? || user.last_seen_at < 15.minutes.ago) }

private
def set_last_seen_at
  current_user.update_column(:last_seen_at, Time.now)
end
```

Devise plugin makes similar behaviour happen (just last seen, without optimizations): https://github.com/ctide/devise_lastseenable

Comment: Good find. Some more improvements:
`before_action :set_last_seen_at, if: -> { user_signed_in? && (current_user.last_seen_at.nil? || current_user.last_seen_at < 15.minutes.ago) }`.

And seems like it's better to use `Time.zone.now` instead of `Time.now`.