# Users online Rails3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am following [this  guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504130/whos-online-using-devise-in-rails)  I have User model.

In **ApplicationController**:

```
after_filter :user_activity

private

def user_activity
  current_user.try :touch
end
```

In **User model**:

```
def online?
  updated_at > 10.minutes.ago
end
```

How can I access all users that are online?
I tried in view:

```
<%= user.online? %>
```

I got this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `user'
```

Some tips ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `User` model `<%= User.online %>` and make scope instead of method (or static method):

```
scope :online, where(:updated_at > 10.minutes.ago)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8518787/724036) is an answer actually (except that you should call `User.online`, not `online?` which is different method).

Comment: @zushe That scope should go inside Users controller ?