# Devise session length counter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session, devise, counter, duration

I need to count how long each user is logged in - I'm using now devise - is there a feature/plugin for Rails/devise that counts this? 
This is **not** a question about setting 'keep me logged in' option - please keep that in mind ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer SO threads: 
1. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184973/rails-using-devise-to-show-online-users) for a simple, but imperfect logic about finding out who is online. 
2. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504130/whos-online-using-devise-in-rails) for a full-fledged plugin solution.